# Excel: sum the last entries at month end query

Tags: excel

I have a list of entries on a spreadsheet with a date and a percentage score. I need help in devising a formula whereby a user can select a month end date (i.e. 31 Jan) from a drop down and the average percentage of the last 15 entries will be returned.

There may be multiple entries on the same date but only the last 15 (based on the month end date) should be used. For simplicity the entries would be input in date order.

Let me know if you require any further information.

Thank you

P

Comment: Thanks Dave for your response. Is there a way of limiting the last number of cases checked to a value of less than 15 if there was less that 15 entries in a month?

Comment: You could replace the -15 with -MIN(COUNTA(A:A)-1,15) (assuming there is a title in row one, otherwise you could take out the -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in column A, the values in column B and the dropdown in D2:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(D2,A:A,1)-1,0,-15,1))
```

*For this to work, your data will need to be sorted in date order!

**Also won't work if there are less than 15 rows (I assume this wouldn't be the case anyway)